# Extending metadata store with importMetadata

Tags: breeze

I am trying to add some properties to the Breeze metadatastore in order to send some additional information related to an entity from the client over to the server. I was hoping I could do this by just extending the entity with the values that I wanted and fetching them from EntityInfo.UnmappedValuesMap, but they did not show up there. Leading me to this approach.

Basically I got a track that I want to add a filename to, so I am adding an extra property to a custom metadata that I import into my metadatastore with allow merge set to true:

```
var customMetadata = {
    "structuralTypes": [{
        "shortName": "Track",
        "namespace": "Namespace.DataBase",
        "dataProperties": [
            {
                "nameOnServer": "Id",
                "isPartOfKey": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Filename",
                "custom": {
                    "description": "Name of file"
                }
            }],

    }]
};
metadatastore.importMetadata(customMetadata, true);
```

Track is already in the metadatastore and when I check the metadatastore after the import, track is overrided by the new type, when all I want is to add one property. All the other entities after Track is missing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want with unmapped properties.

Take a look at these topics in the breeze documentation.

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/entity-serialization

Answer (score 2):

After reading up on Extending Entities as suggested by @Jay Traband, I got this working by using the registerEntityTypeCtor and providing my own constructor for track. My values ended up in unmapped properties which was what I wanted :)

```
metadatastore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Track", Track);
var Track = (function () {
    function Track() {
        this.Filename = "";
        this.FileRef = "";
    }
    return Track;
})();
```